# React Native error: Duplicate __self prop found

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I keep trying to boot up my react-native app (with `react-native run-ios`) and getting:

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: App.tsx: /path/to/entry/file/App.tsx: Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.
  36 |   return (
  37 |     <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
> 38 |       <Text
     |       ^
  39 |         style={[
  40 |           styles.sectionTitle,
  41 |           {
```

I can't find any references to `transform-react-jsx-source` or `transform-react-jsx-self` anywhere. How can I get my app to run?